# Get the last activity per user per day in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have many users. Each time a user uses their smartphone it register them. I am determining the last time each user used their smartphone each day.
Additionally smartphone usages from 18:00 to 06:00, the next day, should be considered as an entry on the previous day. I have created a dummy example.

I did the following:

1. First subtract the number of hours.
2. Sort the data frame based on user and date time.
3. Get the last row.

Is there a more efficient approach to this? Are there other tips I can follow to improve my code?

```
df_example = {'id': [1,1,1,1,1],
             'activity': [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 19, 30, 1),
                         datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 20, 22, 2),
                         datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 2, 13, 2),
                         datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 3, 19, 12, 2),
                         datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 3, 21, 3, 1)
                         ]}
df_example = pd.DataFrame(df_example, columns = ['id', 'activity'])
df_example['activity'] = df_example['activity'] - datetime.timedelta(hours=6, minutes=0)
df_example['date'] = df_example['activity'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df_example.sort_values(by=['id', 'activity'])
df_example.groupby(['id', 'date']).tail(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `tail`, if you only need one item there are the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) methods, which do exactly what you think they would do with grouped dataframes:

```
df_example.groupby(['id', 'date']).last()
```

I doubt there is a faster way to create the `activity` column. And you have to create a new one because of your requirement with what counts to which day.

But you can speed up getting the date. Using `apply` with a `lambda` [is about the second slowest way](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) to work with `pandas` (manual Python `for` loops are slower). Instead use the [vectorized datetime functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html):

```
df_example['date'] = df_example['activity'].dt.date
```

---

**Potential bug**:
Note that `df_example.sort_values(by=['id', 'activity'])` returns the sorted dataframe, it does not modify it inplace. Either assign it back to `df_example`, or use `inplace=True`.

The same is true for `groupby`, you probably want to assign the result to a variable as well in order to do something else with it afterwards.

---

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). While it recommends using spaces around the `=` operator when using it for assignment, it recommends using no spaces when using it for keyword arguments.